# Bootable device not found after clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 UEFI on Acer

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, uefi, acer

I have a single boot Acer laptop where I performed a clean installation of Ubuntu.

After boot it shows a *bootable device not found* error.

I tried running boot-repair and when it finishes it says that repair was successful, but the error persists.

The laptop did not have any operating system previously installed on it.

I also tried to deactivate UEFI, but the desktop would not load correctly making it impossible to install.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: so what error do you get when you boot ?

Comment: A shot in the dark: Try [disabling Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) Note that Secure Boot is not synonymous with UEFI. In fact, given your configuration, it's best to boot in EFI/UEFI mode, so you should *not* attempt to disable UEFI (aka enable BIOS, CSM, or legacy support). You might also want to read [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) I wrote on EFI-mode installs or [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) Ubuntu community wiki on the subject.

Comment: bodhi.zazen -> The actual error is literally "Bootable device not".
Rod Smith -> I couldn't find an option to disabling secure boot,only to disable UEFI, anyway I'll check it again and I'll post how it went.

Comment: Any feed-back on the above?  Disabling UEFI is definitely the way to go!

Comment: Disabling UEFI lead to track pad ad other problems after install.  The solution was to set up a bios password and the an option to manually add trusted boot files appeared.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got it work at Acer Aspire ES1-111-C827. Should be working on other devices, too. Probably the BIOS-entries are a bit different. All you have to do is to register the newly installed UEFI-file as trusted for executing in BIOS-security options.

Before installation goto BIOS-Settings, make sure to have this:

- Security: set supervisor password;
- Boot - BootMode: UEFI;
- Boot - SecureBoot: enabled;

After installation again go to BIOS-Settings

- Security - Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- HDD0 appears, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- EFI appears, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- Go to `<ubuntu>` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- Choose the first entry with `.efi` (`shimx64.efi` on my device) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- Give it a name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;

Save changes on exiting BIOS and restart. That's it.

Some people report that they still needed to change the boot order.

Comment: Acer password setting: http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29349/

Comment: It also worked for me to do all the above steps after installation.

Comment: I followed the instructions; for some reason I don't get the 'Select UEFI file as trusted' option; although I can create the new boot with shimx64.efi as boot file; but it doesn't start the OS nevertheless.

Comment: Installing with UEFI (without CSM) and SecureMode, and then disabling SecureBoot and switching to UEFI (without CSM) after install made it work for me.