# Details of installing Ubuntu aside of Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have Acer Aspire V 15 Nitro with pre-installed Windows 10. I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 too.

I tried to follow this:

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and some guides on the internet too.

I am never able to boot Ubuntu. I do not even see the USB with Ubuntu on it, Windows bootloader everytime boots Windows even if it has the lowest priority, set via BIOS settings, and the USB the highest.

I can install ubuntu, because in advanced restart options, there is an option to boot from USB. While installing I can choose "Install Ubuntu aside of Windows 10", but Ubuntu never boots while choosing this option.

I tried this booting with secure boot enabled and disabled too.

I thought that there may be a problem, because I have 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD, but Itried to install everything on SSD and it did not work.

Best option is to install it the way, that both systems work, use SSD for system and HDD split in half for data. Detailed answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ubuntu 14.04.2 desktop alongside windows 7 grub not shown until secure boot is disabled](http://askubuntu.com/questions/684946/ubuntu-14-04-2-desktop-alongside-windows-7-grub-not-shown-until-secure-boot-is-d)

Comment: This is not duplicate of that question, there was not mentioned that Acer notebooks does not show grub as boot option automatically and you have to add it manually as was written in answer and comments on answer below. In this was problem and trust me I searched a lot and I found an answer after a week. There is many of questions like this one but if someone asks generally and someone replies for general notebook, it does not solve problem for those with Acer notebook. I am busy now, but I will improve my installation once more and improve my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just a short answer, which I found somewhere here on askubuntu.

On all Acer notebooks you will never see grub2/ubuntu option until you add it manually. So you have to find this in BIOS and add it.

I will try improve this answer as soon as I will have time.

Comment: In the UEFI settings, set a supervisor password, and then additional options are available, among them, setting trust on the Ubuntu bootloaders shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)