# Dual boot with Windows 8.1 and Kubuntu 15.04 on Acer notebook (failed boot-repair)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 15.04

I am trying to install Kubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 8.1. Right now I do not need Windows, but I don't want to get rid of it, in case I need it in the future.

The problem is that I could not get the Grub menu to show up. I disabled Secure Boot, fast Boot and installed Kubuntu three times through a Live USB. The installation process is smooth. I create the partitions manually (/home, / and swap) and install normally after that. The problem is that the computer always boots into Windows, without showing the GRUB menu.

I tried the boot-repair through the live USB and still doesn't work. I got the following link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12782400

Comment: Acer requires a Supervisory password & setting "trust" on Ubuntu's efi boot files. Details on password & trust setting:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi

Answer (score 0):

In the UEFI / Bios you can configure which bootloader should be loaded first by the UEFI. Maybe you should check if this is configured correctly. It needs to be set to load GRUB first, not the Windows Bootloader.
In my UEFI setup there is a tab named "Boot" where an option "Boot device priority" can be found. Please make sure that the entry "ubuntu [...]" is on top of that list, not "Windows [...]"

Comment: I went there, but the is no entry named Ubuntu. I tried putting Windows with the last priority, but it still boots into windows.

Answer (score 0):

Please write what entries are in your boot device priority list.

Probably there's no entry you need because something is wrong with the Ubuntu boot partition. If there's really no Ubuntu entry then check from windows or from Ubuntu liveCD with GParted if there is /dev/sda1 partition in fat32 with boot-flag. If there's no such partition, then you must create it.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer.  Please either explain how to check these things, or how to actually create partitions if none exist.  In its current form this sounds like a half-answer, half-comment.