# Grub Dual boot Windows 10 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS trouble to load Windows from Grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Windows 10 on an Acer V5-472-6419 laptop. It created about 4 other partitions. After that I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I disabled fast startup in Windows 10.

When I choose Windows Boot Manager on GRUB I get an error message that starts with /EndEntire and ends with /EndEntire error: cannot load image. If I change the order of the operating systems on the setup I get to load Windows 10 or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but not by using GRUB.

Error image:

[image]

I tried to add a menuentry but it didn't work for me:

```
menuentry ‘Windows 10′ {
set root='(hd0,msdos1)’
chainloader +1
}
```

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) in Ubuntu. This will produce a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your document here. Without the information provided by Boot Info Script (or equivalent obtained in other ways), any answer will be mostly guesswork.

Comment: I already did as you told me. The file is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/12872491/

Comment: Your computer boots in EFI mode, and the manual `menuentry` you tried to add will only work for BIOS mode, so that's a dead end. Everything else looks like it *should* work. My guess is that there's filesystem damage on your ESP. Disabling Fast Startup can often help with that, but you say you've already done that. My next suggestion is to back up the ESP (`/dev/sda2` for you), create a fresh FAT32 filesystem on that partition, and restore its files. This is not risk-free, though; an error could make things worse.

Comment: If I change the boot order in the BIOS, I am able to boot Windows 10 normally. I'm not able to load it with the GRUB menu only.

Comment: I am thinking of doing a clean install of the whole disk. Should I install Windows 10 first or Ubuntu? Should I let Windows 10 make it's own partitions?

Comment: Please try my suggestion first; it's much less radical, and even though it may seem like a long shot, it's worth trying before the more serious re-installation option. As to re-installing, do Windows first, I'd create a 550MiB ESP first using some other tool, then let Windows create its partitions. (If possible, leave space for Ubuntu, but do not create Ubuntu partitions with Windows' tools.) With that done, run the Ubuntu installer and create Ubuntu partitions in it.

Comment: I wiped the disk using sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M, then installed Windows 10 normally leaving space for Ubuntu, then installed Ubuntu 15.04 which created its own partitions and ended up in the exact same place with the exact same error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RnGpV.jpg

Comment: I was wondering if when installing Ubuntu, I should create an EFI partition for Ubuntu.

Comment: I am really lost and about to lose it!

Comment: Did you install both Ubuntu & Windows in UEFI boot mode? And you should only have one ESP - efi system partition per device, although UEFI and a few systems allow more. And Acer requires you to set "trust" on any UEFI boot files (other than Windows?). http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi Otherwise follow Rod Smith's suggestion on rEFInd.

Comment: I have discovered this: with a totally clean disk, a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04.3 (ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso), Ubuntu gets registered in the setup of the laptop. With a clean install of Ubuntu 15.04 (ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso) this does not happen, and Ubuntu does not boot. Both installations creating an UEFI partition (500 MB), a root partition (ext4) (60000MB) and a swap partion (8000MB).

Comment: Now I have discovered this: I wiped the disk first. Then I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 (ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso). After that I installed Windows 10 spanish single language 64 bits (Win10_SingleLang_Spanish_x64.iso). Windows 10 did not destroy ubuntu and used the same EFI partition I had created for Ubuntu. I can boot both operating systems selecting their boot priority in the laptop setup. I don't have grub installed with this way of installing. Maybe I could try to install rEFInd now.

Comment: I had the same issue. I found the following tutorial. http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/ This completely fixed my issue!! So happy!

Answer (score 1):

I completely spaced out and forgot about this bug, which is almost certainly the cause of your problem:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464

There are a number of workarounds noted in the bug report, but the two simplest are:

- Disable Secure Boot in your firmware. Details of how to do this vary from one system to another. I wrote a Web page that shows a few examples; see [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) if you need help.
- Install my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) It will take over as your primary boot program, and it lacks this problem, so you should be able to boot either OS with Secure Boot enabled. You can install it from the Debian package or using the PPA.

Comment: I encountered this issue dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 and Win 10 (EFI mode) on an Acer E1 laptop. Disabling secure boot in the BIOS fixed it for me. I have no idea what secure boot did, so I don't miss it :)

Comment: Secure Boot is intended to offer some protection against boot-time malware. As a general rule, I recommend leaving it enabled if that's practical; but there are times when it creates big enough problems that it's not practical to leave it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot into ubuntu if yes then try sudo update-grub if not fixed then i think its a compatabilaty problem when 14.04 was released there was no windows 10 if sudo update-grub dosent fixes the issue try installing 15.04 insted .

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I get exactly the same error as with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: As I said in another comment, Ubuntu 15.04 does not properly install itself in the setup of the laptop. I tried wiping the disk and installing Ubuntu 15.04 alone in the disk and i wouldn't boot and wasn't registered in the setup.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to Install Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with a start menu to select the OS at startup on an Acer v5-472-6419 Laptop**

1. Wipe the disk

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda (or the right path to your hdd)
   ```
2. Install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64 bits

   I used this ISO: ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
   I wiped the pendrive using GPARTED
   I delete its partition, create a new FAT32 partition
   I mount it with the file explorer, selecting the USB drive
   I installed it to a pendrive using:

   ```
   7z x /media/DATA/SW/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso -o/media/3228-9BA3/

   7z x path-to-UBUNTU-ISO/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso -o/mount-point-to-pendrive/
   ```

   I installed ubuntu creating my own partitions:

   500 MB EFI partition
   60000 MB Ubuntu root partition ext4 (mount point /)
   8000 MB Swap drive
3. Install Windows 10 Single Language (Spanish) 64 bits

   I wiped the pendrive using GPARTED
   I deleted its partition, created a new FAT32 partition
   I mounted it with the file explorer, selecting the USB drive
   I installed it to a pendrive using:

   ```
   7z x /media/DATA/SW/Win10_SingleLang_Spanish_x64.iso -o/media/E731-CA23/

   7z x path-to-WINDOWS-10-ISO/Win10_SingleLang_Spanish_x64.iso -o/mount-point-to-pendrive
   ```

   I installed Windows 10 to a 60 GB NTFS partition.

   Windows 10 automatically used the EFI partition I had created before during Ubuntu installation.

   I disabled Windows 10 fast boot:

   Go to Power options -> Select the behaviour of the on/off button
   Go to the bottom of the window and check out (deselect) the fast startup option
4. At this point I was able to boot either Ubuntu or Windows by selecting them on the BIOS/Setup of the laptop.

   Change the boot order and leave Ubuntu as a prior option to Windows 10.
5. Boot to Ubuntu and install rEFInd Boot Manager

   First add the repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
   ```

Update:

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

Install rEFInd:

```
    sudo apt-get install refind
```

THE END

At this point everything was running and I could boot both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 with a start menu provided by rEFInd

What I gained installing first Ubuntu, and after that Windows 10 was that the Ubuntu installation didn't install GRUB2 which have proven not to work properly before. I don't know at this point if Grub would have interfered with rEFInd but I think it would.

I created an NTFS DATA partition with the remaining space (about 300GB) to be used with both operating systems.

Thanks for all the work and collaboration! Specially to Rod Smith
I can't express here how happy I am! I thought I would never accomplish this!

Comment: This procedure does not work with Ubuntu 15.04 because it does not register properly in the BIOS/Setup of the laptop and it does not boot.