# Ubuntu boot on windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I recently have installed ubuntu in my computer, alongside windows 10. The installation went fine (from an USB file, downloaded from Ubuntu.com ) but when i try to restart my computer starts automatically windows 10 and doesn't show me what OS I can choose. I've tried turning off fast startup, but it doesn't seem to work. Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: so it boots right into Ubuntu if so open up a terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T and type in this command `sudo update-grub`

Comment: How and where should I type that? Do i need the USB again?

Comment: It boots right to windows, not ubuntu. I want to choose it!

Comment: @Neil It boots right to windows, not to ubuntu. Should i disable UEFI? I didn't disable it when i installed ubuntu.

Comment: Do not turn off UEFI. What brand/model system. Many will not auto boot any entry that does not say Windows. But there are work arounds. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Comment: @oldfred Acer Aspire V3-572G-70Q8. Came with windows 8.1 and i updated it to windows 10.

Comment: @oldfred Why is so dificult to install dual boot on windows 10?

Comment: BIOS was not always easy, it depended on system. UEFI complicates it now as it is both BIOS & UEFI and Secure boot and many more settings in UEFI. But your issue is Acer. Acer requires you to set password and then drill down to Ubuntu/grub efi boot files and set trust. Details on password & trust setting:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold 'Shift' at startup of your computer. It should bring you to the grub menu. If you want to permanently change it, go into Ubuntu and go to terminal, type in:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Go to the line where it says:

`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`

And change the number 0 to 10 or what you prefer (this is the time it stays on the grub menu and when time's up it automatically boots into the selected option, but i do recommend 10 though). Change `true` to `false` and then save the file and quit it. After editing the file, type in the terminal:

`sudo update-grub`

And restart to see if it worked. Please say if it didn't work!