# Do I need to partition C: or can I used D:?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu in Dual Boot with my Windows 10 and I know that I need make some partitions to install ubuntu.

At the moment in my windows 10 I have both a C: and a D: drive:

C: - has Windows installed and his where I save my files/pics/etc

D: - is where I have my games and some random things, nothing important and I don't think I need a lot of space(I don't install a lot of games at the same time)

And because of this I would prefer to shrink D: instead, and use that space.

So my question is: Do I need to shrink the C: drive or can I shrink the D:
drive instead?

[Disk Management - My Drives atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwtGm.png)

I only installed in dual boot once and that PC only had C: drive so I'm not really sure.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Ubuntu cares not what you shrink, just give it some free space.

Comment: It looks like Acer with UEFI. So be sure to install in UEFI mode. And Acer requires "trust" on grub's efi boot files. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system and:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Acer Trust: http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi You may find threads, suggesting to down grade UEFI, but newer threads say very latest UEFI from Acer works. So make sure you have newest Acer UEFI version.

Comment: As mikewhatever said, it technically doesn't matter at all.  Just give it some free space, *somewhere*, and it can install there and run.  In practice though, you might have other reasons to set it up one way or another, and it can be confusing at first to figure out what the installer calls each drive or partition.  Thus, when I set up my laptop to dual-boot (or re-install the same or a different system), I pull the quick-remove storage-only drive so that I don't accidentally end up with it depending on that to boot to *any* system, which is entirely possible if you get things mixed up.

Comment: Also, the DOS/Windows drive letters do **not** correspond to physical drives.  They are partitions, which may or may not be on the same physical drive or different drives.  For example, a pre-built, ready-to-go PC might have exactly one physical hard drive that is partitioned into a C:/ drive for normal use and a D:/ drive for "recovery".  So....how is that recovery "drive" supposed to handle a hard drive crash if there's really just the one physical drive???  Seems kinda useless to me, unless you screw up your settings I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have it all on one HDD shrink your D: drive for installing ubuntu.

Be aware that you may want for a proper running system at least 10-15 GB (means i  you want to install alot of tools like me :D the more is the better) and around double size of your ram for a swap partition (don't kill me im just repeating what i have read mostly) but i think you will suffice with less swap if you already have lots of ram in your system because the less likely the system is going to use the swap partition.

just leave the free partition space unallocated, start from your LIVE CD and choose to install alongside Windows.

Comment: 10-15 GB is not enough for current Ubuntu. [System requirements say 25GB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) and I'd agree with it. You can install with less, but there won't be space for anything and it will always cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As mikewhatever said in a comment, it technically doesn't matter at all.  Just give it some free space, *somewhere*, and it can install there and run.

In practice though, you might have other reasons to set it up one way or another, and it can be confusing at first to figure out what the installer calls each drive or partition.  Thus, when I set up my laptop to dual-boot (or re-install the same or a different system), I pull the quick-remove storage-only drive so that I don't accidentally end up depending on that to boot to *any* system, which is entirely possible if you get things mixed up.

---

Also, the DOS/Windows drive letters do **not** correspond to physical drives.  They are partitions, which may or may not be on the same physical drive or different drives.  For example, a pre-built, ready-to-go PC might have exactly one physical hard drive that is partitioned into a C:/ drive for normal use and a D:/ drive for "recovery".  The screenshot in the question above shows this, except that the "recovery" partition in this case doesn't have a drive letter.  That probably means it's formatted with something that Windows can't read (but the OEM recovery tool can), possibly to prevent a user from messing it up like you could with earlier versions of that idea.

Anyway, since there's really just the one physical drive in the entire system, how is the "recovery drive" supposed to handle a hard drive crash???  Seems kinda useless to me, unless you screw up your settings I guess, or install some crapware, and the drive itself is fine.  And Windows 10 has its own recovery tools that don't use a separate partition anyway.  (I've used them to reset a PC that I set up for a specific application, and then went a different direction.)

So I'd be tempted to just blow away the recovery partition and use that space for something else.  Either absorb it into a neighboring partition (grow the neighbor into it), or put Ubuntu (or whatever) there if it fits comfortably.