# Can't boot Ubuntu 16.04 without dvd / usb

Tags: boot, usb, dvd

I just got Acer E 15, and I want to use only Ubuntu 16.04 on it. I have used "rufus" on my primary laptop (win7) to burn Ubuntu installation iso on usb.
I reordered the  boot priority to boot from  usb and I started the installation on my Acer E 15(which is without os) with usb  and I successfully installed Ubuntu on Acer.

After that I changed the boot priority order so my HDD is first and remove usb. but after restart, Acer wont boot without usb.(boot mode was UEFI, and secure boot was enabled) and only option is to use usb and use TRY option of ubuntu.

After much forum reading I started Ubuntu in TRY mode and was trying to install grub on HDD but it wont let me install. I used repair and grub was installed on HDD(I think). after that I can start Ubuntu without usb and all look good and I can see my user name that I set in installation part, but every time I restart, there is error that ask me to pick way to boot, there are 2 options, Unknown -(my hdd name) and Windows boot -(my hdd name), As I said, I did not have any OS on Acer before this installation.

Then I burnt Ubuntu iso on DVD with "unetbootin" and all was the same like with usb, and I burn it on second DVD with "rufus" and all was the same again.
In installation type I did it as "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", and after that didn't help a lot of times, I pick "Something else" :

There I try a lot of different stuff, but nothing help me. I made New Partition Table =

- dev/sda1 ext4 /  (root)
- dev/sda2 swap
- dev/sda3 /home

  but it always ask me to make EFI partition, so I add that too. I was trying to add and /boot partition too.

And in "Device for boot loader installation:" normally i set to /dev/sda (hdd name), but I was trying to set it to EFI partition or in root partition or /boot partition, but nothing change. (I reinstall a lot of times and every time different type of partitions)

I'm sorry for long post and if my English is bad, but I really need some help, this is first time that I'm trying Ubuntu. I'm just hoping someone will be able to help me, so I don't need to boot from usb/dvd and that I don't get error all the time when i restart OS. (I want Ubuntu to be my only OS).

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Make sure you have latest UEFI from Acer. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  then do Something Else install: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation then go into UEFI, set a supervisory password and enable "trust" on grub's efi boot files: http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's working good now ! I don't need usb/dvd and I dont have error when I resetart. Thank you so much sir ! 
I just want to ask one more thing, after first step when I make 3 partition, and when I start second step do I "New Partition Table" and make other partitions, or I just add the new ones to first 3 that I made ?
I add partitions from second step to first 3 partitions(for step one), and all look good now, but I just want to see what is corect. And one more time, thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

You got an Acer *UEFI* laptop. You should start by creating a new partition table - GPT style for your Acer hardisk. You can do that by booting any live Ubuntu, open GParted and use the command for creating partition table - GPT.

Secondly, in order for GRUB (Ubuntu's bootloader) to install correctly, you have to make sure that your USB drive has a GPT partition table style, too. You can easily do that with Rufus, by choosing *GPT partititoning for UEFI PC* option. Create a new FAT32 partition and write the Ubuntu iso file again to USB.

Third, i'd use a very simple partitioning scheme: sda1 -EFI partition, sda2 - Ubuntu (boot) partition, sda3 - swap, sda4 - home (or backup partition). Why so? EFI partition ALWAYS needs to be first, because that's were the partition table data will be written. Ubuntu partition would be your main partition - where you install and boot Ubuntu from.

Swap can theoretically be placed anywhere on disk, just make sure it's not in the first cylinder (cylinder 1024) of the disk. Swap acts as virtual RAM and it will be overwritten intensively. Wearing down the first cylinder will render you harddisk unusable. Swap size should be = 1,5...2 x RAM size. Using oversized swap is not advisable!! Swap is just a little helper, not a main workhorse.

Home or backup partition is entirely your choice. It will be your *personal stuff* partition.

Important thing: You should never install GRUB to any (particular) partition. You should install it in the root of your harddisk (e.g. /sda). If you have multiple internal disks, then GRUB should be installed in the root of your first harddisk (as listed in GParted).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.
I did all as you told me, but it wont let me make it if i dont make / (root) partition
so I made like this >  dev/sda1 efi (primary)
dev/sda2 exit4 /boot (primary)
dev/sda3 swap (logical)
dev/sda4 ext4 / root (primary)
dev/sda5 ext4 /home (primary)
but they it say "Force UEFI installation?" ...If you continue to install debian in UEFI mode.. and so on. If you have time, please tell me what did I do wrong or what do I need to do more.

Comment: I've been installing debian-based linuxes for almost 10 years now, mostly on Asus and MSI hardware, and i have yet to encounter a situation like yours. Sorry, i'm not familiar with Acer hardware, still i can see no obvious reason for such a root partition. Maybe it's a very new thing i'm not aware of. Anyways, i'm just glad oldfred's comment have been helpful to you.

Comment: I think that the main reason for the problem , is my poor knowledge of system installation, but now evrything is doing good, thank you for fast answer and your time.