# Ubuntu 16.04 Default Partition Names - I don't know which is which

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, swap

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 16 and didn't change anything in the partitions.  Now I have 3 partitions, and I don't know which partition is what.  I ask so that I can increase/add a swap,and create the recommended partitions from the answer at [Ubuntu 16.04 partition help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783195/ubuntu-16-04-partition-help) (/opt, /root, /home).

This is what I have: [GParted Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiPZ6.png)

1. /dev/sda1 (fat32, /boot/efi, 512MB)
2. /dev/sda2 (ext2, /boot, 244MB)
3. /dev/sda3 (crypt-luks, not mounted, 465GB)
4. unallocated, 1MB

Is anyone able to discern how I could label these so that they make sense to a newbie?
Thank you!

Comment: There is really no need to create separate /opt, /root, /home. IMHO, the answer you wish to follow is a poor advice. With encryption enabled, Gparted can't see what's in crypt-luks, it has to be decrypted first.

Comment: @mike Does that mean that my swap is likely within the encrypted partition?  My main concern is swap, and that I don't mess anything up.

Comment: It might be. You can check from within Ubuntu with the `free -h` command.