# 16.04 not bootable - fresh laptop, no preinstalled OS

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

Laptop: [acer, Aspire V 13](http://www.x-kom.pl/p/292326-notebook-laptop-133-acer-v3-372-i5-6267u-8gb-240-fhd-iris.html) V3-372-57M8

Notes:

1. I'm able to load ubuntu from flash disk (which is how I am writing this post)
2. holding shift after reboot wont bring up the grub menu
3. Using boot repair didnt help, here is the [log](http://paste2.org/PV0dOU46).
   Note the "No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda."
   In some online resources I read it is not an issue with new systems.
4. adding "boot" flag to /dev/sda2 didn't work (file system ext4, see screenshot)
5. I'm trying to boot in UEFI mode

[image: gparted]

I tried for a couple of hours to get this to work, no luck so far ...

Comment: But are you trying to boot in Legacy mode or EFI? Is UEFI installed correctly in the BIOS?

Comment: Every Acer we have seen with UEFI boot requires you to set a supervisory password and enable "trust" on the grub boot files. Some may mention downgrade UEFI, but newer ones say newest UEFI works. Make sure you have newest UEFI from Acer. Some also require boot parameters. http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi and: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742

Comment: @oldfred the second link solved my problem, thanks! I can't accept your comment as an answer tho, care to post it as it's on answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on an Acer Aspire and I've been facing similar issues. Tried boot-repair, manually updating and reinstalling grub, turning secure boot off with no success.

You have to select the grubx64 uefi file as trusted from BIOS. Detailed instructions can be found here - https://askubuntu.com/a/630662/237187

Comment: Thanks for the help, notice it was resolved already in the comments tho :)

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed, good to hear :)