# Trying to install Ubuntu along Win 10 on Packard Bell EN TG71 BM

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have a laptop currently running Win 10 (upgraded from Win 8.1), and now I wanted to try Ubuntu. So I decided to attempt to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Win 10, but it would not work.

I have tried several ways, both choosing the option to "install Ubuntu alongside Windows" when installing, as well as the method with "other options". I even tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows (and then update later), as I heard that this method would be easier to get to work with the Windows Bootloader. And yes, I did try get Grub to work, but to no avail.

My laptop is a Packard Bell EN TG78BM.

Comment: Packard Bell is part of Acer and Acer is the only vendor we have seen with a requirement of setting an UEFI supervisory password and then enable "trust" on the Ubuntu/grub .efi boot files in the ESP. So is Packard Bell the same?  Also make sure you have latest UEFI from packard Bell. http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi Some also mention downgrading UEFI, but newer threads say very newest work for Acer. Do not know about yours. another Packard Bell: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234019

Comment: Boot from the live cd open the terminal and type `dd if=/dev/sda count=63 | hexdump -C >mbr.txt && less mbr.txt` , Scroll down , can you see somthing like `windows OEM` ...?

Comment: I have tried to open the file "mbr.txt" via the terminal all I get is long vertical row of  "~" and then finally  (END ).

Comment: I am very close to give up trying Ubuntu in any other way than a virtual machine. I have updated the bios/EFI with an official update from Packard Bells homepage, which brought it from 1.03 to 1.10, but still nothing. I did have a hint of luck, with so I could open Grub by entering the F12 boot menu, but then I got stock with it asking for BASH commands. I have tried using EasyBCD to get edit the Boot menu, but first when opening the program it states that "due to limitations set by Microsoft, many of EasyBCD's multi-booting features cannot be used in EFI mode and has been disabled"