# Can't get rid of «Default Boot Device Missing» message on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I recently bought an Acer Swift 3 ultrabook pre-loaded with Windows 10, which I wiped out to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 in single-boot. In my case installs are generally a breeze, but not this time. Long story short, I ended up with a «*No Bootable Device*» message on boot. I fixed the problem with Boot-Repair. The ultrabook now works perfectly.

After the repair, however, I kept getting at boot time a blue window with this message : « *Default Boot Device Missing or Boot failed. Insert recovery media and hit any key* ». Hitting a key would lead me to a Boot Manager with only one entry: *1- Windows boot manager*. Selecting it would then get me to Grub, with the usual Ubuntu option.

I search the net, found the post [Bootable device not found after clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 UEFI on Acer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi/653202#653202), modified the BIOS-settings as instructed («*Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing*»  and so on), to no avail. The blue rectangle just won't go away at boot. The only change is that there is now a Ubuntu entry in the Windows Boot manager.

Secure Boot is enabled.

The boot priority order is:

1. EFI File Boot 0 : Ubuntu
2. Windows Boot Manager
3. HDD : HF S256G39TND-N210A

By the way, when I modified the BIOS-Settings in the Security tab, I found three .efi files in **HDDO - EFI - ubuntu**. I selected the first one (as suggested), and left the other two untouched: `grubx64.efi` and `MokManager.efi`.

I could of course reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, but since I've already installed a whole bunch of applications, I’d rather find a workaround.

The output of `sudo efibootmgr -v` is:

```
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0002,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,f7b03efc-87a7-467e-af43-862381b9c710,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0001* ubuntu    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(1,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,f7b03efc-87a7-467e-af43-862381b9c710,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\fwupx64.efi)A01 ..
Boot0002* Unknown Device:   HD(1,GPT,f7b03efc-87a7-467e-af43-862381b9c710,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Comment: Please type `sudo efibootmgr -v` in a Terminal window in Ubuntu. You should then either *edit* your question to cut-and-paste the output there, adding four spaces to the start of each line; or post the output to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to my problem was found by user **oldfred**, from the *Ubuntu forums*.

[Can't get rid of «Default Boot Device Missing» message on boot](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2345082)

From the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v`
he deduced that:

> It looks like your default UEFI boot entry 0001 is fwupx64.efi which is the grub menu entry to get into UEFI.
>   If you have secure boot on, you want to boot shimx64.efi which is 0002 but shown as unknown device.

On his advice I went back into UEFI and set "trust" and a label on the shimx64.efi file.

Et voilà!

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you two links with answers for your Swift 3 troubles.
[How to get GRUB boot option?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870022/how-to-get-grub-boot-option/940871#940871)
see both the answers in this question and the comments as well.

there are two parts to this.
Part 1 - getting Ubuntu with a mainline 4.12 and above kernel and installing it
part 2 - enabling secure boot, adding your efi file as secure, disabling secure boot, and making grub come on top of the boot list.

good luck ;)