# Wiped Windows and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Acer Travelmate P but can't find bootloader

Tags: boot, 18.04, bootloader, acer

I decided to switch from Windows to Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, an acer travelmate p.

I booted up with the USB ISO. I did a regular install, no updates. I did the delete and install style build. Install went through without a hitch.

Now my laptop boot loops. A message comes up super fast saying something along the lines of can't find boot loader, then it restarts.

When I go back into Linux via the USB, I do a parted print and I see my esp partition with the boot flag. I also see the ext4 with everything else on it.

I also tried a efibootmgr.

I got 4 results. windows as 0000, iba ge slot as 0001, my HD as 0002, and the USB im on as 0003.
I deleted the Windows one, but I did notice Ubuntu wasn't on there. I'm a little stumped about what my next step would be now. Any advice?

Edit: I successfully got mint 17.3 installed weirdly enough. That gave me the idea to try 16.04.4 and then upgrading after that. The later had the same results as installing 18.04 unfortunately

Comment: All Acer require you to set "trust" from within the UEFI on the Ubuntu/grub .efi boot files. Details: Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/870022/how-to-get-grub-boot-option/870074
& https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I was unable to find the correct entry on the security page of bios, even after setting a security Password

Comment: Some that have older systems, have to upgrade UEFI. Some versions from Acer are missing the entry you need. Older threads had users downgrading UEFI, but newer threads say you need to update UEFI. Acer Cloudbook shows screen for selecting trust
http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/340-ubuntu-install-acer-aspire-cloudbook-431
http://community.acer.com/t5/Predator-Laptops/Dual-Boot-Ubuntu-Win10-Step-by-step-guide/m-p/430392#U430392

Comment: so i had to reinstall windows to update bios. once i updated bios it let me choose between legacy and uefi on my "boot" tab in my bios. Then i  I reinstalled ubuntu 18.04 and i expected to have to go back and add it to the trusted boot loaders as per your first comment but this was unnecessary. It booted and it worked. all is well with the world. TYVM for all your help :)

Comment: Hi gbux, would it be possible to adjust your question to include the Acer model that you are using? Other folks experiencing problems with the same Acer model would then find what worked for you and it might help them out. It'd be helpful if you quickly outlined what worked for you in an answer and marked it as the solution to your question too.

Comment: Just realised I can edit the Question myself (awaiting peer review) - if you could outline your solution as an answer though, that'd still be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to repair the boot with Boot-repair using the USB with UBUNTU LIVE.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did as you suggested and ran boot repair. I had done this twice. Once on the current install I had on there and then again after I wiped everything, put a clean install and then before rebooting I did boot repair. Neither seemed to work as both times I had the same experience when rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

So I had to reinstall windows to update bios. I went to [acer download site](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) and downloaded the most recent bios. once i updated bios it let me choose between legacy and uefi on my "boot" tab in my bios. I did set a security password again but i dont know for certain if that added anything to this process. Then I reinstalled ubuntu 18.04 and i expected to have to go back and add it to the trusted boot loaders in the security tab of bios but it booted and it worked. all is well with the world.

Comment: Excellent gbux, can you accept your answer by clicking the check mark next to it? Not sure if you need to wait a day or two after asking the question but this tells you what to do - https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer