# Problem in ubuntu and windows 8 dual boot on Acer Aspire E1-571

Tags: dual-boot, acer

I have Windows 8 pre-installed. Today I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire E1-571 in legacy mode. Now by default it is opening Windows, and if I choose legacy mode in boot menu, it is opening Ubuntu.

But there is no option of dual boot. Suggest me the way to get the option of dual boot?

Comment: your windows might be in UEFI mode and you installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode. That is why you are not able to Dual boot. you need to Install Ubuntu also in UEFI mode to have dual boot.

Comment: And how to install in uefi mode

Comment: the same way you installed in Legacy Mode. if you are installing with USB.. you will have two options..UEFI usb & usb.. if you choose usb, its Legacy..go to BIOS and set it to boot only in UEFI mode.. then you can be sure that you are installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: All Acer in UEFI mode also need trust settings. See: Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/870022/how-to-get-grub-boot-option/870074 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/886536/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-acer-with-preinstalled-windows-10-home