# Boot problem - installed ubuntu 16.04 and restarted. But ubuntu is not coming.

Tags: boot

I installed ubuntu 16.04 
It showed successfully installed restart system.
I removed the bootable usb and restated. But it did some hardware check and showed again 'no bootable device found' !

Please help me with this

Comment: This sounds like it could be a bios problem. Can you check your boot order settings are ok?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I have downloaded ubuntu 16.04 and made my USB as bootable device by using rufus

Comment: What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is already a topic about this with some detailed information off what might go wrong. please check this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi). The steps given in the solution are the following:

Before installation goto BIOS-Settings, make sure to have this:

- Security: set supervisor password;
- Boot - BootMode: UEFI;
- Boot - SecureBoot: enabled;

After installation again go to BIOS-Settings

- Security - Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing `Enter`;
- HDD0 appears `Enter`;
- EFI appears `Enter`;
- goto  `Enter`;
- choose the first entry with .efi ("shimx64.efi" at my device) `Enter`;
- give it a name `Enter`;
- save changes on exit BIOS;
- restart

Comment: Hi, I am trying to install ubuntu. Not as a dual OS. I've installed 3 times and all the times it showed like installation is completed and if  i restart, it is doing some HW testing and finallu no bootable devices found !

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/740301)

Comment: @Pilot6 I'll Edit it and add it. thanks for the information

Comment: This is a good answer only if computer is Acer which has the unique requirement of setting UEFI password & enabling trust. Other brands often need other work arounds. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 0):

Please give us more information so we can figure out what has gone wrong in your particular situation. Are you installing Ubuntu onto a computer without an operating system on it yet, installing it to replace another operating system, or trying to dual boot two operating systems? And do you know if you're computer's hard drive has the older BIOS or the newer UEFI firmware interface?

Either way, if the computer can't find any bootable devices, then it shouldn't be a problem with boot priority (it would just keep going down the list until it found something). One option would be to plug your USB back in, and run the startup repair option. This could fix things if you're only wanting to run Ubuntu. If you're trying to dual boot windows, you may have somehow removed its startup manager which likely requires you to get a windows recovery disk to access again. If you have a UEFI device, then you could need to manually ensure the grub shim is listed in the boot order. It all depends on your particular scenario

Comment: If you don't have enough information to answer, then please don't answer. Answer some clear questions and gain some reputation, then you will be able to post comments on questions like this to get the required information and post specific, definitive answers instead of vague, speculative ones

Answer (score 0):

Run your machine with USB bootable device in live mode. Go to BOOT repair application and select Repair the GRUB booting. Now shut down the system. Remove bootable disk and start the machine.