# Dual boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

i'm having a problem regarding booting into Ubuntu, more exactly Grub 2 bootloader, after a Windows 10 installation followed by Ubuntu 16.04, on the same SSD hard-drive, only different partitions. After installing Windows 10 i've disabled Secure Boot from BIOS and hibernation & fast startup from Windows 10. Still, after installing Ubuntu with manually created partitions for root, swap & home, the Grub 2 won't start; still boots into Windows 10. Also, if i'd use EasyBCD in Windows, i can't create Ubuntu option for boot/install Grub. I don't know what i did wrong. There are like 100 tutorials for installing Windows 10 + Ubuntu but it seems that all are mostly the same. Maybe i should select Windows's Boot Manager's partition as Device for Boot loader installation (see the attached picture)? Thanks!

[Ubuntu disk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHlPn.jpg)

[EasyBCD EFI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RksXy.png)

[Windows bootloader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww6Mi.jpg)

Later edit: after following this steps (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291335&p=13341757#post13341757) now i'm able to select Grub2's bootloader at boot, but after booting into Ubuntu, i get some errors (see the 3rd picture). However, if i don't press F12 at boot, it boots into Windows, despide i've put Ubuntu 1st at boot priority in BIOS (first picture).

[Ubuntu's options to boot from in BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJiOB.jpg)

[Grub2 bootloader's options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7M49.jpg)

[Errors when booting into Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T955H.jpg)

Comment: you need to boot the Ubuntu  install disk in EFI mode.

Comment: I don't really understand. Could you be more explicit? Thanks! :)

Comment: you have to install Ubuntu in EFI mode

Comment: You mean that i have to enable secure boot from BIOS then reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: you have to turn off Legacy boot mode.

Comment: If UEFI do not use EasyBCD, that was more for BIOS boot and then not really recommended. What brand/model system? Some require work arounds even if Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi some systems also require UEFI updates and updates to firmware for SSD.

Comment: laptop Acer Aspire V15 Nitro (Aspire VN7-593G)

Comment: Acer has unique requirement. You have to turn on Secure Boot, Set UEFI password and enable "trust" on .efi boot files. https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi/653202#653202 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291335&p=13341757#post13341757

Comment: are these 2 links the same steps? the second is more ellaborate. thanks!

Comment: did the steps in your attached tutorial, but now i have a problem when booting into Ubuntu. I'll edit my 1st post to attach some pictures.

Comment: try this: `sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/boot --efi-directory==/boot/efi --bootloader-id="Ubuntu"` Make sure UEFI is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was basically oldfred's tutorial to enalbe "trust" on Ubuntu's EFI files for Acer systems and UjwalBhagat advice to reinstall Ubuntu. After a reinstall with internet connection enabled and updates & 3rd party software selected (for install), not it works (i added the new EFI files as "trust" and put the one with grub2 first option for boot), at startup i get the Grub2 bootloader and i can boot into Ubuntu or Windows 10. Thanks guys for your time!

PS: If you know how to mark your comments as answers (oldfred & UjwalBhagat), please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem.
Solution: Boot into BIOS and go to bootable devices and increase the priority of Ubuntu partition than that of Windows. Save the change and reboot.
Now you will see the GRUB boot menu and you should also see boot 'To Windows' option on GRUB menu, if not, then boot into Ubuntu, open terminal and type `sudo update-grub` it will ask for the password, type in your password and click enter and reboot. Next time it will boot into GRUB and you will also see the Boot into Windows option.
Have a nice day.

Comment: I already put Windows under Ubuntu  in BIOS and it still doesn't boot into it. Also i get an error when booting into Ubuntu (with F12), so i cannot use Terminal. Please see my edit & screenshots at my first post. Thanks!

Comment: Your secure boot looks enabled to me, can you disable it?

Comment: it doesn't matter if secure boot is enabled. it wouldn't cause this problem

Comment: In my case, it(secure boot) would not let me boot into Ubuntu if I enable it.

Comment: It's useless, i disabled secure boot, still nothing changes.

Comment: @BR4TO92 Can you boot into Ubuntu Live using bootable USB?

Comment: Yes, i can boot into it

Comment: @BR4TO92 Can you check the MD5 hash of the iso with the one on Ubuntu's website?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I have only one bootable USB that i've installed. It's from Ubuntu's website (the iso file).

Comment: @BR4TO92 Download this(http://www.winmd5.com/) software, select the iso you downloaded then go to (http://releases.ubuntu.com/) select the version you downloaded in that download MD5SUMS file and open it using notepad and paste its value in WinMD5 software to verify. I can help you over RDP also.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Did what you said, i have a match

Comment: @UjwalBhagat Any new input?

Comment: @BR4TO92 Try to install Ubuntu again. BTW what are your computer specifications such as CPU and motherboard?

Comment: @UjwalBhagat When installing again should i select Something else option, delete and reassing the partitions as they are now, and install it with Internet access (last time i haven't allowed Internet access). Specs: Intel i7 7700-HQ, 2.8GHz, 4 cores, 16Gb Ram, Intel HD Graphincs & NVidia GeForce GTX 1060.

Comment: @BR4TO92 There should be an option to reinstall ubuntu, it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDWhk.png  EDIT: Glad your problem is solved.

Comment: @UjwalBhagat thanks for the advice. After reinstalling Ubuntu as you said and putting again the EFI files as "trust", now it boots directly into Grub2. How can i mark your post as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: @BR4TO92 You cannot mark a comment as an answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: @UjwalBhagat Thanks again for the answer. Have a nice day!