# Setup dual boot menu with WIndows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I know this has been asked before and I've waded through a lot of very long posts trying to find a way to do this but everything I've tried has failed, hence the question.

Looking for a simple way to have a dual boot menu (either the windows boot manager or grub) for both OSs. I've installed Ubuntu on a separate partition on my laptop but it will still only boot to windows.

It is set to UEFI boot and secure boot is off in BIOS, it will boot to the USB stick but taking that out boots direct into windows again.

I've tried running boot-repair from Ubuntu on the stick and I've tried EasyBCD in Windows - neither of which worked.

Would appreciate a quick/simple guide on how to setup the dual boot menu. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What brand/model system? Some require work arounds as they do not follow UEFI specs. Can you boot Ubuntu from UEFI menu? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: It is an Acer E5-553G-T03K, about a month old. Yes, I can boot to the Ubuntu USB stick but not the installed partition - it simply doesn't see it in Bios or the boot menu that comes up when you hit F12 on startup.

Comment: Go back to your live USB stick. When Ubuntu has booted up, open terminal (r.click desktop) and type sudo gparted. When it opens look at device sda1 (might be under sda2 or 3). It should be about 500MB. What are shown under Columns ´File System´, ´Mount Point´ and ´Flags´?

Comment: Acer has a unique requirement of setting "trust" in UEFI on the ubuntu/grub .efi boot files. see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi or: Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742  Some also have reported that you have to have updated UEFI from Acer to have settings in UEFI to enable trust.

Comment: Running Gparted gives these results: /dev/sda1 14.65 GB, Filesystem fat32, Mount Point /cdrom, Flags msftdata

Comment: I also followed instructions on secure boot and selecting a trusted efi file. I used all four listed under Ubuntu and added them to the trusted list. It still boots to Windows.

Comment: Not doable then - I'm stuck with Windoze because I bought an Acer ?

Answer (score 0):

There are subtle problems, we'd probably need details to really fix.  Of course, you need to boot into Ubuntu in order to get the thing fixed, but your booter does not want to go there.  You can get there booting from the USB?

When your computer boots, it goes straight to windows?  You don't see a grub menu to choose the OS at all?

If yes, I have ideas. It may be you do need to follow the usual advice about starting Ubuntu and re-running the grub install, but the thing may be installed, but just not found.

I have encountered the problem you see in the following context. The hard disks are recognized at startup in an unexpected order.  The boot process will use the first OS loader it finds. If your first found drive has Windoze, you get that.

Sometimes it happens that when you run the Linux install, it notices the drives in a different order.  The one you think should be found and boot the grub menu actually is found second by the BIOS. The other drive has the  old Windoze boot loader.  For whatever reason, the Linux install sees the drives in different orders.  If that's what is happening, your BIOS may allow you to alter the order of the drives that are found.

Also, in the OS setup you may have a way to prevent the Windows only drive from being seen as a bootable device. I'd check, anyway

Before we understood that was the problem, we actually swapped cables from motherboard to disk drives. When we want Windows to boot for maintenance, the technician has to go into the bios and reverse the boot order.  If you think problem is like that, I can check those systems, get details.

Other ideas. It is possible the bootloader was not installed in the correct location.  In the installer, do you remember deciding where to install the boot loader? You may have to designate which drive, or even a partition.  If your drives are using the older Master Boot Record style to create partitions, then for sure the bootable thing needs to be set a active.  If you have the newer style partitions (GPT), I don't think you have to mark a partition bootable (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/partitioning).

Maybe we should check how your drives are laid out. I have one traditional SATA and one of the newer type SSD.

```
$ lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0            7:0    0   100G  0 loop
└─veracrypt1_0 253:1    0   100G  0 dm
  └─veracrypt1 253:2    0   100G  0 dm    /home/pauljohn/TrueMounted
sda              8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1           8:1    0 214.9G  0 part  /home/pauljohn/VM
└─sda2           8:2    0   538G  0 part  /home/pauljohn/LinuxDownloads
nvme0n1        259:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1    259:1    0   500M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2    259:2    0     3G  0 part
[snip]
```

The sda is the ordinary one.  The one labeled NVMe is the SSD drive.  That's where I have the boot record installed. If you also have that kind of ssd, the way to see the partitions is parted, like so:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/nvme0n1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p
Model: NVMe Device (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   fat32           EFI system partition  boot, esp
 2      525MB   3747MB  3221MB  fat32           Basic data partition  msftdata
 3      3747MB  98.1GB  94.4GB  ext4            root
 4      98.1GB  151GB   52.4GB  ext4
 5      151GB   178GB   27.1GB  ext4
 6      178GB   188GB   10.5GB  ext4            opt
 7      188GB   223GB   34.6GB  linux-swap(v1)
 8      223GB   512GB   289GB   ext4            home
```

Note on partition 1, it has the boot attribute.  I have no other
partitions with the boot attribute, there's no confusion.  I suspect you have more than one, and it is finding the wrong one first.

Good luck, let us know  what you try, but be explicit. Write it down as exactly as you can. The  grub framework tries to make things automatic. That's great when it works. Less good otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yes when it starts up it goes directly to windows with no menus. In bios the two main options are windows boot loader and the hard drive (plus usb devices below), I've tried both. I can also boot to the Ubuntu USB stick no problem. I have installed Ubuntu 4 separate times now trying different options, the last one I told it to put the grub loader on sda0, which I think is the primary drive the machine checks before booting to Windows. It is a laptop with 1 HDD that has Windows on one partition, Ubuntu on the other and the third is empty. Really dont know what to try next