# Installed Ubuntu alongside windows 10 but can't switch between os

Tags: dual-boot, bios

I have installed Ubuntu into its own partition but when I boot my Acer laptop it takes me straight into windows I have checked boot menu nothing and I have checked the primary is and it only has windows

Can someone help me with a method on how to switch between Ubuntu and windows

Comment: Did you disable "Secure Boot"? (if UEFI)

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio yes I have it disabled

Comment: Many Acer need UEFI update. And all Acer need you to enable "trust" from within UEFI on the ubuntu/grub UEFI boot entries. https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi-on-acer Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

You could [see this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003&fbclid=IwAR1jApDxnO9inbtNivoLbygIfuUvQXlAfPRhfaDBCV3HpP3S0mOrIoj1B4w)
The steps are:

1. Shut down, then while starting back up repeatedly press the F2 button many times until the BIOS setup utility loads.

2. In the *Main* menu, set the *F12 Boot Menu* option to *Enabled*. Press F10 to Save and Exit, then once Windows loads shut down again.

3. Insert your USB flash drive with your 64-bit Ubuntu installer on it.

4. Power on and keep pressing F12 until the boot menu pops up. Select the flash drive, boot, and install Ubuntu.

This is where things get tricky...

5. After Ubuntu reboots, it will boot back into Windows.   Shut down again. Reboot and hit F2 to enter the BIOS again.

6. Under *Security*, choose *Set Supervisor Password*, and set one. You will need this password any time you go back into the BIOS. A bunch of options on the page should change from gray to blue.

7. The "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" should now be available. If it's not available, check that Secure Boot is still Enabled, if not, enable it. Select it, and navigate to HDD0 -> EFI -> Ubuntu -> grubx64.efi. The BIOS will ask you for a name for it; I called it Grub.

8. Press F10 to save and exit, then immediately press F2 again to re-enter the BIOS.

9. Now go to *Boot*, set *Secure Boot* to *Disabled*, and press the arrow key to go down to the bottom of the list to your new "Grub" entry. Press F6 until it's at the top of the list.

10. Press F10 one last time. Your system should now reboot to the grub bootloader!