# Blank screen display after new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation (on a system having windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, nvidia

So I could boot from USB in my Acer AN515 system with only [uefi](/questions/tagged/uefi) boot option. I had secure boot enabled and got the system installed. When it rebooted after installation, it got stuck in a black screen with some TPM error. I had to manually use power button to restart the system and happily it booted to Ubuntu. But there, when I login (to my account or guest), it logs in and after that I see a blank screen (not black, it shows Ubuntu background). That's it, keyboard or mouse is not affecting anything nor is any icon displayed on screen.
I tried following as well:

1. Erase and reinstall Ubuntu
2. Reinstall Ubuntu with Download updates while installing and Install 3rd party software
3. In login screen, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1/F3</kbd>. When I do this, my mouse disappears and system becomes unresponsive to keyboard or mouse. I see no change in monitor display.

I allocated 50GB for root directory, 240 GB for home and 600 MB for the UEFI (or something) partition.

System Specs:

1. 8 GB RAM
2. 256 GB SSD (has windows)
3. 1TB HDD (Ubuntu installed on this, SSD has not enough space)
4. Nvidia 1050TI graphics card

Note: If I give wrong password, it shows login fail.

Comment: Does the Grub menu show up? If so, press 'e' and add `nomodeset` to the same line where "quiet splash" is. Then it should boot normally in low graphics. Next install the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootable device not found after clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 UEFI on Acer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi-on-acer)