# boot-repair fails with 'No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.'

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I'm running a Windows 10/ubuntu dual boot system and have successfully used grub as boot manager until today. However, today the system unexpectedly failed to display grub at startup and instead booted to windows right away. I verified in UEFI that linux has higher boot priority, yet the problem persists. I also created a ubuntu live boot medium and ran bootrepair withit, albeit without success. The pastebin can be found here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/t4SxpDWPGp/

I admit not being able to interpret this log in full. Any pointers as to where the underlying problem may lie are appreciated.

Additional info: I tried both with activated and deactivated secureboot, without any effect.

Comment: Boot-Repair does not fully show NVMe drives in the first part of report. With UEFI boot you do not have boot loader in MBR, but boot files in an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32) which is your /dev/nvme0n1p2. Your UEFI shows an "unknown device" which is typical for Acer where you have not set "trust". You must have set trust on other entries, so is unknown a new entry that needs trust setting? https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi-on-acer

Comment: Thank you very much, that did indeed solve the problem! The current kernel version still does not boot but that is a separate issue; the system works again as desired with the previous kernel version

/edit If you reformat your response as an answer, I will mark it as the solution as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a combination of multiple things:

1. the boot-repair did work in that it successfully reinstalled grub.
2. however, it was also necessary to set the newly installed grub version as trusted in UEFI, as pointed out by oldfred above (thank you very much!); refer to [Bootable device not found after clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 UEFI on Acer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi-on-acer) for more details
3. further, I needed to set the boot order such that the trusted grub was in front of windows in UEFI

Thank you again, oldfred!