# Ubuntu 18.04 installation stuck at Grub2 installation in Acer laptop

Tags: boot, 16.04, 18.04, grub2, system-installation

I am first time going to use Linux for that i am trying to installing Ubuntu 18.04 and tried 16.04 also in my Acer laptop Acer Aspire ES 15-> "ES1-533-P21L". But every time my laptop hangs when progress bar is reaching to "Installing the 'grub2' package". I tried 3 times but getting the same result and it's very frustrating now. Can anybody help me what i can to solve this issue. 
Thanks in advance!!!

[image]

Comment: Have you internet connection during installation ? I'm not sure but it might need to download the grub2 packages first in order to install them.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi i tried in both way, with internet and without internet both. But getting same result.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Acer is known to be tricky; anyhow the first steps should be disable secure boot in bios/uefi and most likely fastboot. wish you luck

Comment: @db429 can you please point out some steps in answer section so that i can follow that?

Comment: Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
Acer are all pretty much the same. Details on password & trust setting:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi

Comment: @oldfred I am installing only ubuntu in my laptop. No windows is there

Comment: Skip anything related to Windows. The install process for Ubuntu is the same and that is one of the few Acer specific sets of instructions. Also:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: If you have removed Windows, are you booting in UEFI or BIOS mode? Best to use UEFI for newer computers. But then you must have an ESP - efi system partition for grub to install into.UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation