# BOOT Error on (Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not found)

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade, sudo, bootloader

I had my office laptop (acer singleboot)at my home which i upgraded (sudo apt update) after a long time. ununtu eduunbuntu [image (bootscreen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpd4f.jpg)18.04. Then after i restart it is not booting.

Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you will need to have a Live USB or Live DVD handy. Fortunately, it's not too difficult. Here's what you need to do:

1. Boot the machine using the Live USB / Live DVD and select "Try Ubuntu"
2. Once the Live session has finished booting, open a terminal
3. List the partitions on your notebook using `fdisk`:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

   You should see something like this:

   ```
   Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
   /dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    2000895   1998848   976M EFI System
   /dev/nvme0n1p2   2000896  936214527 934213632 445.5G Linux filesystem
   /dev/nvme0n1p3 936214528 1000214527  64000000  30.5G Linux swap
   ```

   ***Note:** Your machine might show device names like* `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, *and so on.*
4. Identify the device that is of type `EFI System`. This is where your computer boots from.
5. Mount the `EFI System` partition to `/mnt` so that you can access it:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to replace* `/dev/nmve0n1p1` *with the proper device name for your computer's EFI System partition.*
6. Switch to the super user:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
7. Change to the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` directory on the EFI partition:

   ```
   cd /mnt/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
   ```
8. List the contents of the directory using `ll`. You should see something like this:

   ```
   drwx------ 3 root root    4096  1月  6 14:39 ./
   drwx------ 4 root root    4096  7月  2  2019 ../
   -rwx------ 1 root root     108 10月  2 11:38 BOOTX64.CSV*
   drwx------ 2 root root    4096  1月 20 00:20 fw/
   -rwx------ 1 root root   60602  6月 19  2020 fwupdx64.efi*
   -rwx------ 1 root root     117 10月  2 11:38 grub.cfg*
   -rwx------ 1 root root 1681280 10月  2 11:38 grubx64.efi*
   -rwx------ 1 root root 1277024 10月  2 11:38 mmx64.efi*
   -rwx------ 1 root root 1341560 10月  2 11:38 shimx64.efi*
   ```
9. Identify and copy an `.efi` file.
   • Do you have an `mmx64.efi` file in the list? Copy it to `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT`:

   ```
   cp mmx64.efi /mnt/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/mmx64.efi
   ```

   • If you do not have an `mmx64.efi` file but you do have `grubx64.efi`, copy that to `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` with the name `mmx64.efi`:

   ```
   cp grubx64.efi /mnt/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/mmx64.efi
   ```
10. Reboot the machine, remembering to remove the Live USB / DVD so that you boot from the hard drive.

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: could i do it with a usb of other ubuntu version without changing os in my laptop

Comment: Found answer in https://askubuntu.com/a/653202/1174208